# Regarding file system Support in Linux Mint xfce

Tags: linux, linux-mint, filesystems, ntfs, fat32

Will my FAT32 and NTFS USB and hard disks work in Linux ?
I mean can windows compatible file systems USB and hard disks work in Linux?

**[EDIT]**
By work I mean - like I have a NTFS hard disk so can I access it's file and cut, copy , paste, rename amd create new files in hard disk in Linux ?

Comment: what do you mean by `work`?

Comment: @jsotola see the edited question now ⬆️

Comment: linux uses [ntfs-3g](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/ntfs-3g/info) for r/w a long time now, so no problems with dual-boot (only windows still can't read ext4 partitions)

Comment: @alecxs my laptop memory is less so I can't use dual boot properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, NTFS and FAT32 are supported as read-write in Linux Mint XFCE.

> But it is suggested to transfer from NTFS to exFAT because
>
> - exFAT has more supported devices than NTFS like XBox,etc.
> - If you want to connect to Mac then NTFS opens as read-only in mac but exFAT opens as read-write mode.

**FILE SYSTEM SUPPORTED BY LINUX**

ext2,ext3,ext4,NTFS,VFAT,FAT32,exFAT and many more.

> BUT you would notice that when you connect exFAT Drives then Linux
>   gives error messages. So to enable exFAT support read below.

**Enabling exFAT support in Linux**

Open terminal and type below line and HIT ENTER

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Now when you connect exFAT USB or Disk it will open easily.

> However Windows only support NTFS,FAT32 and exFAT (listed file systems
>   are the majorly used ones).